# How make a simple node API to serve GeoJSON from PostGIS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, postgis

I'm trying to write a node API that will serve straight-up GeoJSON, directly usable by apps such as Leaflet. My SQL command is this:

```sql
SELECT 
json_build_object('type', 'FeatureCollection', 'features', json_agg(ST_AsGeoJSON(t.*)::json)) 
FROM 
my_table AS t
```

and the API code looks like this:

```
router.get('/api/data', async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const data = await pool.query(
            "SELECT json_build_object('type', 'FeatureCollection', 'features', json_agg(ST_AsGeoJSON(t.*)::json)) FROM my_table AS t"
            );
        res.json(data);
```

and the JSON being served by the API looks like this:

```json
{
"command":"SELECT",
"rowCount":1,
"oid":null,
"rows":[{
"json_build_object":{
"type":"FeatureCollection",
"features":[{
"type":"Feature","geometry":{
"type":"MultiPolygon",
"coordinates":
...
```

Obviously, I want just the `{"type":"FeatureCollection" ...` to be served by the API, but its wrapped in the `command`, `rows`, and `json_build_object`.

How do I write my API code to output standard GeoJSON and nothing more?

This is a continuation from a question I asked yesterday that gets at the heart of the problem I was having. I've read the PostGIS docs, and looked all over Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow to no avail. I feel like its an easy fix, I just don't know because I'm new to this kind of development.

Answer (score 0):

you are right there, try something like this

```
 app.get('/geojson', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const client = await pool.connect();
    const result = await client.query(`SELECT json_build_object('type', 'FeatureCollection', 'features', json_agg(ST_AsGeoJSON(t.*)::json)) FROM us_states AS t`);

    // Send the GeoJSON as the response
    res.json(result.rows[0].geojson);

    client.release();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
});
```